# Можно ли всегда обозначать переменные через var?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли в javascript всегда обозначать переменные var. Если, что различия между ними я знаю, просто интересно

Comment: при полном понимании что делаешь - можно, но в целом не имеет смысла. Полный контроль в итоге закончится и за всем уследить будет невозможно

Comment: Десять лет назад все только var и использовали. Но в 2022 году — зачем?

Comment: Не стоит, т.к. во первых так код бывает более изолированным, а во вторых не допускает случайное переопределение одной и той же переменной, что может привести к неожиданным результатам. Но можно его везде использовать, причём не самым очевидным способом, чтобы испрортить жизнь следующему программисту, который будет работать с вашим кодом)))

Comment: не только можно, но и нужно. Все остальное было придумано для неосиляторов, которые пишут грязный код и не могут сами писать нормально

Answer (score 0):

Можно.
А еще можно называть переменные просто по порядку, ну чтобы не запутаться какие уже использовались в проекте, типа

```
var var1;
...
var var2;
...
var var3;
...
var var4;
```

Много чего можно. Вопрос в том - с какой целью. Если Вы планируете быть частью какой-либо команды, или пишите что-то, что потенциально увидите не только Вы, то ответ **однозначно нет**.
И тут вопрос не только во всплытии переменных или риске ошибок из-за одинаковых названий, например, но и в том, оптимизации кода, количество потребляемых ресурсов.

Comment: По-моему вы восприняли вопрос слишком буквально